# Adding RealmSwift as a subproject: Missing required modules: 'Realm.Private', 'Realm'

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, realm

So I wanted to link to RealmSwift in my own framework and these are the steps I took:

1. Add `RealmSwift` as a subproject

   [image]
2. Link the framework:

   [image]
3. Add the dependency

   [image]
4. Import `RealmSwift` into the Swift file:

   [image]

And I got the error: `Missing required modules: 'Realm.Private', 'Realm'`. How can I solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I can copy the Realm.framework out of the RealmSwift.framework and the message disappears. But then RLMObject is not found. How about you?

Comment: This is still an issue 7years later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to add `/path/to/RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks` 
to the “Framework Search Paths” section in Build Settings

where `/path/to/RealmSwift.framework` is the location of the framework.

This is because `RealmSwift.framework` depends on `Realm.framework` (where the `Realm` and `Realm.Private` modules are defined), which is vendored in its `Frameworks` directory.

Comment: Cocoapods should take care of all this. Is this a bug in the latest version?

Comment: The original question was in reference to using Xcode subprojects, so CocoaPods is irrelevant. You're correct in assuming that CocoaPods takes care of all this setup, however.

Comment: How do I find this path exactly? I'm using SPM.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, turns out that the file that showed the error was used by two different targets. When adding Realm with SPM, we can only select one target. I solved the with the following steps:

1. In the Project Navigator, select the target that lacks Realm
2. In `Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries`, add `RealmSwift` and `Realm`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it shows a Xcode-specific solution in a clear and understandable way without relying on figuring paths manually.

Answer (score 2):

As of Realm [v0.93.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases/tag/v0.93.0), RealmSwift.framework no longer embeds Realm.framework.  This causes the same missing module error message when you upgrade.  You can resolve it by linking directly to both RealmSwift.framework and Realm.framework.  You'll also need to remove any pre-existing strip-frameworks.sh Run Script Phase in your app's target's Build Phases.  This step is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me when I did the pod install...

Make sure you open the appname.xcworkspace file not the appname.xcodeproj after doing the pod-install with CocoaPods.

The error No such module 'RealmSwift' will occur from any file where 'import RealmSwift' is set up if not opened from appname.xcworkspace.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Project Name.
2. Navigate to `Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries`
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGD4J.png)
3. Click the plus sign to add > Select `Realm, RealmSwift` click `Add`
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crMrL.png)
4. Hit `command + b` to build and your problem should go away
   [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0W3e.png)