# Swift Project: "Missing Required Modules" when import a modular framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, module-map

**Setup**

1. I create a swift framework which include C library (CommonCrypto) and a Objective C file.
2. There is no bridge-header in swift project. So I create a `module.modulemap` to import CommonCrypto and Objective-C file into my swift framework.

   module.modulemap content:
   [image]

Here is the module.modulemap sample link:[Importing CommonCrypto in a swift framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248598/importing-commoncrypto-in-a-swift-framework)

3. In project settings, adding modulus.modulusmap path to swift compile[image]

   So, in my swift framework, everything works fine.
   I can use modulus like this

   [image]

**Problem shows**

1. Archive the modular framework and export as a built products.
2. In my swift sample project, add modular framework to Embedded Binaries
   [image]
3. **Error occurs on this line when I use something inside the framework**
   [image]

I have try so many solutions, but still not work.

Similar problems:

> 1. [Swift app: “Missing required module” when importing framework that imports static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757417/swift-app-missing-required-module-when-importing-framework-that-imports-stati)
> 2. [Adding RealmSwift as a subproject: Missing required modules: 'Realm.Private', 'Realm'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168779/adding-realmswift-as-a-subproject-missing-required-modules-realm-private-r)

Is anyone have a good solution for this?
Thx!!

Comment: Do you plan to distribute this framework to others? Or would it be suitable to just keep it in the same Xcode workspace as the project(s) you want to use it in?

Comment: It's a commercial framework. I would distribute this to others and many other unrelated projects. If I use the framework in my own project on my development environment, works fine. But, for the projects on someone's development environment shows the problem.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108539/importing-pure-swift-custom-framework-into-other-swift-project?rq=1

Comment: Thanks man. Finally, I got a solution. It's a bit wired but work fine. I will post it later.

Comment: @HungCLo I had same problem too. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Ok. I found a workaround. Redefine module.modulemap on sample project. ex: module CommonCrypto { }

Comment: @yycking Thanks. I already found out a solution. If you are still interesting about the question, you can see the solution.

Comment: Hi, @HungCLo i have the same problem can you share your solution with me pls?

Comment: Hi, @SOUAHamza, I post an answer as you wish. Hope it helpful.

Comment: Will it be able to hide Objective-C files from the user of this framework?

Answer (score 7):

**Solution**

iOS framework exists as a folder, create a `module.modulemap` to find out library or header file.

1. Setup `module.modulemap` path

   In project/target/Build Settings/Swift Compile - Search Path/Import Path = 
   “${SRCROOT}”
2. Add below to `module.modulemap`

[image]

**Remarks**

You don't have to add module.modulemap to the sample project if the framework is archived on the same development environment.

Comment: Thank you @HungClo , so if i understand i have to add the module map in the project that is using my Framework ? , and i need to run it on other environment

Comment: Exactly, module map helps you find out your framework. It's the same on other environment.

Comment: Thank you, but i need to add the framework to a project outside of the environment without module map , but it seem like impossible for now in SWIFT

Comment: You can find out if the framework share the header files or not in the framework folder. Assume that you can access header files, you also can try the solution. Let me know if it works!~

Comment: I try to reproduce this project but without success.
https://github.com/danieleggert/mixed-swift-objc-framework

Comment: it probably works for you, but take into the account, that the base of your trouble is how you defined module.modulemap. I suggest you check Clang documentation https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-map-language (see framework keyword). without "framework module', your module.modulemap is not available externally.

Comment: @SOUAHamza declare your module as 'framework module' and the module.modulemap will be part of your framework.

Comment: not work for me, since my OC header is not public, it is not visible outside of the framrwork.

Comment: @User9527 since you say it is not visible to the end user. If I keep my OC header as private or project in target membership. I get this error: nclude of non-modular header inside framework module '... Any help!